# Vue doesn't allow me to generate grid-template-columns

Tags: css, vue.js, grid, nuxt.js

I put my code on `style scoped`

This is the output that i want to generate:

```css
.user-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.user-card {
  padding: 1em;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background: #1abc9c;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-grid" v-for="user in allUsers" :key="user.id">
  <div class="user-card" v-if="user.client_id === $route.params.id">
    {{user.name}}
    {{user.email}}
    {{user.phone}}
  </div>
  <div class="user-card" v-if="user.client_id === $route.params.id">
    {{user.name}}
    {{user.email}}
    {{user.phone}}
  </div>
  <div class="user-card" v-if="user.client_id === $route.params.id">
    {{user.name}}
    {{user.email}}
    {{user.phone}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: dont mind the CSS code I just want to express the out that Vue/Nuxt gave me.

But in Vue/Nuxt I'm getting this:

[image]

I tried to change the **auto-fit minmax** to auto-fit, `minmax(200px, 200px)` the size work but the display dont follow the rule.

How can i apply display grid on Vue/Nuxt application?

Answer (score 0):

I put my class out of the `v-for` loop in Vue.